# How to get fields from related tables with Eloquent PHP laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

traer algunos campos me resulta un poco consufo es posible que alguien me explique como hacerlo desde el modelo

I have the following tables [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urbvm.png)

The table course_teacher is the pivot table and contains the field called "is_available".

I would like to make a query

that returns

course_name, teacher_name

and only show me the courses that are active.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider you're using m-n relationship, so your models will be like

```
class Course {
 ...
 public function teachers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class, 'course_teacher');
 }

 public function avaiableTeachers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class, 'course_teacher')->wherePivot('available', 1);
 }

}

class Teacher{
  ...
  public class courses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_teacher');
  }
}
```

At this step, we have defined the m-n relationship for eloquent.

Then, if you want to get courses with assigned teachers (Only available), then the query will be like this:

```
$ courses = Course::with('avaiableTeachers')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your knowledge with me, it was very helpful.